# how to get an input value like in browser's prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create my own `prompt` funcionality.

In the example below how can I say:

```
var x = my_prompt('DO SOMETHING');
console.log(x);
```

So clicking on `btnb` I need the value of `inputxt` derived after `btna` is clicked.

```js
$('#btnb').on('click', function(){
my_prompt('DO SOMETHING');
});

function my_prompt(info){
$('#dginfo').text(info);
$('#dialog').show();
$('#inputxt').focus();
}
```

```css
.dialog{
display:none;
position:fixed;
width:50%;
left:25%;
top:25px;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dialog' id='dialog'>
<div id='dginfo'></div>
<input type='text' class='inputxt' id='inputxt'>
<button id='btna'>OK</div>
</div>

<button id='btnb'>CLICK</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pass a callback to `my_prompt`, which gets invoked when the button is clicked:

```js
$('#btnb').on('click', function() {
  my_prompt('DO SOMETHING', (x) => {
    console.log('input entered: ' + x);
  });
});

function my_prompt(info, callback) {
  $('#dginfo').text(info);
  $('#dialog').show();
  $('#inputxt').focus();
  $('#btna').on('click', () => {
    callback($('#inputxt').val());
    $('#btna').off('click');
    $('#dialog').hide();
  });
}
```

```css
.dialog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dialog' id='dialog'>
  <div id='dginfo'></div>
  <input type='text' class='inputxt' id='inputxt'>
  <button id='btna'>OK</div>
</div>

<button id='btnb'>CLICK</div>
```

To additionally add a listener for `enter`:

```js
$('#btnb').on('click', function() {
  my_prompt('DO SOMETHING', (x) => {
    console.log('input entered: ' + x);
  });
});

$('#inputxt').on('keypress', ({ keyCode }) => {
  if (keyCode === 13) {
    $('#btna').click();
  }
});
function my_prompt(info, callback) {
  $('#dginfo').text(info);
  $('#dialog').show();
  $('#inputxt').focus();
  $('#btna').on('click', () => {
    callback($('#inputxt').val());
    $('#btna').off('click');
    $('#dialog').hide();
  });
}
```

```css
.dialog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dialog' id='dialog'>
  <div id='dginfo'></div>
  <input type='text' class='inputxt' id='inputxt'>
  <button id='btna'>OK</div>
</div>

<button id='btnb'>CLICK</div>
```

Comment: could you pls write the same in case user press `Enter - keyCode 13` inside `inputxt` -  instead of click on `btna`?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a  variable to the return value of `my_prompt`, and add an event listener to do this:

```js
$('#btnb').on('click', function() {
  var data = my_prompt('DO SOMETHING');
});

function my_prompt(info) {
  $('#dginfo').text(info);
  $('#dialog').show();
  $('#inputxt').focus();
  return $("#btna").on("click", function() {
    return $("#inputxt").val(); 
}
```

```css
.dialog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dialog' id='dialog'>
  <div id='dginfo'></div>
  <input type='text' class='inputxt' id='inputxt'>
  <button id='btna'>OK</div>
</div>

<button id='btnb'>CLICK</div>
```